# Kernel Panic - not Syncing: VFS: unknown-block 179,2

Tags: kernel

I'm running raperberry pi 3 with noobs. I've seen people have this issue in the past, however my keyboard isnt working at all when i try to turn the raspberry pi on. Nothing wrong with the keyboard, bought it out of the box yesterday and it works on a different computer.

Comment: Ended up just reformatting the sd card and downloading / moving noobs onto it again. I would delete the post but I have no idea how.

Comment: Normally the error would indicate a faulty partition 2, but NOOBS doesn’t use partition 2, so this is unanswerable unless you say what you did

Comment: Honestly I have no idea, I was trying to download and use RetroPie I probably fat fingered something and screwed it up but thankfully nothing important lost other than some time :P

Comment: You should be able to delete your own question.